# Spring data JPA: embedded ID error when saving the entity

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity classes:

```java
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrganizationCyclePlageKey implements Serializable {
 @Column(name = "organization_id")
    Long organizationId;

    @Column(name = "cycle_plages_id")
    Long cyclePlagesId;
...
equals() and hashCode() methods come here


@Entity
@Table(name = "organization_cycle_plages")
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrganizationCyclePlage {
@EmbeddedId
    private OrganizationCyclePlageKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("organizationId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")
    Organization organization;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("cyclePlagesId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "cycle_plages_id")
    CyclePlage cyclePlage;

...
other attributes
}


@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class CyclePlage extends AbstractEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cyclePlage")
    private Set<OrganizationCyclePlage> organizationCyclePlages;
...
}

@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Getter
@Setter
public class Organization extends AbstractEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organization")
    private Set<OrganizationCyclePlage> organizationCyclePlages = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

SpringBoot app starts up normally without errors.
But when I try to save an instance of `OrganizationCyclePlage`:

```java
OrganizationCyclePlage ocp = new OrganizationCyclePlage();
ocp.setOrganization(organization);
ocp.setCyclePlage(cyclePlage);
organizationCyclePlageRepository.save(ocp);
```

it raises the error when calling `organizationCyclePlageRepository.save(ocp)`:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [361] value by reflection : [class com.XXXX.OrganizationCyclePlageKey.cyclePlagesId] setter of com.XXXX.OrganizationCyclePlageKey.cyclePlagesId
```

What's wrong with these relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the constructor into the `OrganizationCyclePlageKey` class to init the foreign keys values as well a default constructor via `@NoArgsConstructor` annotation:

```java
    public OrganizationCyclePlageKey(Long organizationId, Long cyclePlagesId) {
        this.organizationId = organizationId;
        this.cyclePlagesId = cyclePlagesId;
    }
```

and init the `OrganizationCyclePlageKey` instance in the `OrganizationCyclePlage` class:

```java
public class OrganizationCyclePlage {
    private OrganizationCyclePlageKey id = new OrganizationCyclePlageKey();
...
}
```